# Custom order by

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

I need to order a result set by a substring of the file name. The substring is the date.

For example:

```
select * from mytable where file_name like '%202112%'
order by name_file desc;
```

Result set is for example this:

1. qwerty_20211220_120220
2. asdfgh_20211229_121005
3. zxcvbn_20211223_121151

How to do for order by a portion of string date contains in name_file?

thanks to everyone

Comment: Will the format always be exactly `[some_text]_YYYYMMDD_HH24MISS`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write an expression that extracts the date from the string and then use that expression in your `ORDER BY`.

An easy way to do that, with your sample data, might be:

```
select * from files
order by substr(file_name,-15);
```

I.e., sort by the last 15 positions of the filename (which are the date).

If you are on 12.2 or later, you can do a little better with this:

```
select * from files
order by to_date(substr(file_name,-15) 
             default null on conversion error,'YYYYMMDD"_"HH24MISS') nulls last;
```

This will make sure the data you are sorting on are actual dates.  Any file name in your last that does not have a date stamp will be sorted last.

Comment: @dnlnfr PL/SQL is the in-database compiled programming language. The solution above is Oracle SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, sort by "date" (which is represented by the 1st group of numbers):

```
SQL> select *
  2  from mytable
  3  order by regexp_substr(file_name, '\d+');

FILE_NAME
----------------------
qwerty_20211220_120220
zxcvbn_20211223_121151
asdfgh_20211229_121005
```

Or, sort by *anything* that follows the 1st underline character:

```
SQL> select *
  2  from mytable
  3  order by substr(file_name, instr(file_name, '_'));

FILE_NAME
----------------------
qwerty_20211220_120220
zxcvbn_20211223_121151
asdfgh_20211229_121005

SQL>
```